# It's the size of a brick; What size shirt/shoes do you take?; I have a daughter your age

Tags: grammar, terminology, appositives, postpositive

What is the grammar of the English words "size", "age", etc?

According to Quirk (1985:1293)

> Some noun phrases of measure, denoting size, age, etc, can also be postposed:
>   *A man the size of a giant came up to me.
>
>   Somebody her age shouldn't do such exercises*.

According to *A Functional Analysis of Present Day English on a General Linguistic Basis* (2013:92), such usages are attributive appositions.

Also "plain NP minor determiners" in *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, page 355

Comment: That text calls *the size of a giant* an "attributive apposition"?

Comment: So… what is your actual question here? I think there might be a very good question in this, but “what is the grammar of these words?” is much too broad – you need to specify what exactly it is you’re wondering about that Quirk and _Functional Analysis_ did not answer for you.

Comment: @TRomano Are "A car as big as a house" and "A man as old as the hills" also attributive appositions or are they something else?

Comment: @BoldBen:  I wouldn't call them "appositions".  *A candy-bar **the kind she liked** was stuck in the vending machine and ready to fall out with a little bit of jostling.*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet their specific grammatical properties as a class of "plain NP minor determiners" in Cambridge Grammar of the English Language , page 355

Comment: Not all noun phrases are viable in that position. *A car the **color** she wanted was on the lot* is grammatical whereas *A car the **price** she could afford was on the lot* is ungrammatical or marginal at best.  I would distinguish the viable and the non-viable using the terms "intrinsic quality" and "extrinsic quality".

Comment: @TRomano does it work with the plural, _two cars the colors she wanted_

Comment: @GJC:  The plural seems OK to me: *The salesman showed him two cars the color he liked.*

Comment: @TRomano what about the word colors, _The salesman showed him two cars the colors he liked, namely green and red_

Comment: @GJC:  That seems OK too, if ambiguous, since it could be that each car was a different monotone, or a green body, say, with a white roof, or it could refer to interior/exterior colors. But it's no more ambiguous than *two cars in the colors he liked*.

Comment: @TRomano what about the following _The salesman showed him two cars the sizes he liked_

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of terms like "apposition/appositive" seem to be debated, so it might not be the clearest way to describe this construction.

To me, the construction that you are asking about seems to be along the lines of things that are analyzed as reduced relative clauses or the product of "whiz-deletion": "A man the size of a giant" and "Somebody her age" can be rephrased as "a man ***who was*** the size of a giant" and "somebody ***who was*** her age".

### The definition of "apposition"

#### "Apposition" might be taken to refer to replaceability

One user of this site, BillJ, uses a definition of "apposition" that seems to require that the appositive NP could replace the first NP. That doesn't work in your sentences, which don't entail that "The size of a giant came up to me" and "Her age shouldn't do such exercises". You can see more discussion of this definition of apposition in the comment thread here: [What is the grammatical term of "whose wife was a school teacher"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/441265/what-is-the-grammatical-term-of-whose-wife-was-a-school-teacher/441274#comment1059395_441274)

#### Or apposition might be considered to be associated with non-restrictive constructions specifically

"[Appositional constructions](https://www.lotpublications.nl/Documents/294_fulltext.pdf)", a 2011 thesis by Herman Heringa,  mentions a distinction between "close" apposition, which does not involve parenthetical commas, and "loose" or "non-restrictive" apposition: Heringa says that the latter is "usually taken as apposition proper" (p. 3). Consequently, Heringa only analyzes the non-restrictive construction in his thesis, although he does mention that Meyer (1992) has a different viewpoint, seeing restrictive and non-restrictive constructions as different types of a single phenomenon (p. 3).

Heringa suggests looking at De Vries (2008a) for "more details on the restrictive construction" (p. 5).